# Can't echo two php _GET when forwarding?

Tags: php, get

I am trying to redirect:
showthread.php?threadid=1
to
t-1.html
and
showthreads.php?threadid=1&page=2
to
t-1-p-2.html

This is my code, and I have no idea why it won't echo the threadid when there is a page. It gives me the result
t--p-2.html

```
<html>
    <? $threadlink = $_GET['threadid']; ?>
    <? $pagelink = $_GET['page']; ?>
    <? if ( empty($_GET)) { ?>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=index.html">
    <? } else { ?>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=t-<? echo $threadlink; ?><? if (isset($_GET["page"])){ ?>-p-<? echo $pagelink; ?><? } ?>.html">
    <? } ?>
    </head>
    <body>
    Redirecting to thread id <? echo $threadlink; ?> (if it exists in the archive)
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will redirect the user to `t-threadid-p-page.html` if `threadid` and `page` is set and loads the html below if the `threadid` and `page` is not set.

And if only `threadid` is set it redirects user to `t-threadid.html`

Also if you uncomment the commented lines it will redirect the user back to `index.html` if `threadid` is not set. Then you don't even need the html below it anymore.

```php
<?php
    if(isset($_GET["threadid"])){
        if(isset($_GET["page"])){
            header("Location:t-" . $_GET["threadid"] . "-p-" . $_GET["page"] . ".html");
            exit();
        }
        header("Location:t-" . $_GET["threadid"] . ".html");
        exit();
    }
    // header("Location:index.html");
    // exit();
?>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        Failed to redirect you to your destination.
    </body>
</html>
```